# Universal serial bus Flash drive

Tags: usb

What library file should I download to read and write data through Universal serial bus Flash drive in Raspberry Pi
?

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry Pi is not a simple microcontroller. It runs an Operating System like Raspbian GNU/Linux which takes care of this - you *don't* need dedicated libraries for file I/O on USB drives. 
Raspbian even has a desktop like Windows.

Read up on basic Linux commands [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/)

Read up on file I/O  with C on Linux [here](http://how-to.linuxcareer.com/c-development-on-linux-basic-io-viii)

Comment: Then why it is specified everywhere to download libusb.dev

Comment: LibUSB is needed if you want to use devices without official or inofficial kernel drivers or even **if you make USB device drivers yourself** . I guess it's propably easier to code with than writing drivers inside the kernel